# iOS SLRequest Twitter search credentials access error

Tags: ios, twitter, slrequest

My app uses the integrated Twitter APIs on iOS to receive data from the Twitter REST API. The `/1.1/friends/list.json` and `/1.1/users/lookup.json` endpoints work perfectly on all devices, but the `/1.1/users/search.json` endpoint gives a credentials error for a small group of users.

This is the error response which I receive from the SLRequest on these device:

```
{
    errors = (
        {
            code = 220;
            message = "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource";
        }
    );
}
```

The HTTP status code is 403.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your app has read-write access authorization.
Also check restricting api.twitter.com to SSL/TLS traffic https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239

Also you can refer this link for further troubleshooting [Error Code 220 - "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource" When tryig to get retweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356156/error-code-220-your-credentials-do-not-allow-access-to-this-resource-when-tr)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The permissions shouldn't be the problem since the other API endpoints function normally. My app also uses SSL/TLS to access the Twitter APIs.

I have already looked at that other question but it doesn't include an solution which works for my app.